# Modify a list within a list, using map and lambda through list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Hi everyone I am new to Python and have been trying out how to create lists within lists containing multiples from 1 to 4, with each of them containing the same number of multiples as the number they are being multiplied with. In particular, applying the use of `lambda` and `map` function.

```
 [[0],
  [0, 2],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [0, 4, 8, 12],
  [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]]
```

I have tried several ways and this is the code that I am currently working on, but I have received `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` error. I will really be grateful if someone can point out the mistakes that I have overlooked!

```
list_1 = [[0], [0,1], [0,1,2]]

result = list(map(lambda x, i ,j ,k: x[i][j] * k, list_1, range(3),items in x[i], range(1,3)))

print(result)
```

Comment: The error message is ' NameError: name 'x' is not defined'

Answer (score 0):

You get the `NameError` because one of your parameters to the `map` is `items in x[i]`, and at this point none of those things are defined. Keep in mind that a lambda is equivalent to a function definition; `x` and `i` are the function's names for the parameters that are passed in - they aren't available to be used in defining the other parameters, because you're doing this work outside that scope. (As for `items`, it doesn't appear anywhere else in your code, so of course it isn't defined.)

Fundamentally, none of this logic makes sense. In particular: since you are trying to produce a nested data structure, you should expect nested `map` calls as well.

Take this in smaller steps. Try first to write the code that produces e.g. `[0, 4, 8, 12]` given `4` as an input. Then you can write code that repeatedly calls *that* to make the list of lists that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is too complex for this problem. Instead, use a list comprehension and a single nested `map`:

```
new_result = [list(map(lambda x:i*x, range(i))) for i in range(1, 6)]
```

Output:

```
[[0], [0, 2], [0, 3, 6], [0, 4, 8, 12], [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]]
```

Comment: I ran the code and got 
    [<map at 0x105885358>,
    <map at 0x105885390>,
    <map at 0x1058853c8>,
    <map at 0x105885400>,
    <map at 0x105885438>]
I tried to modify to display the output as shown above but it has been unsuccessful. Would you mind sharing how did you achieve that output?

Comment: @duetette_95: Fixed. I tested the solution in Python2, however, in Python3, map returns an iter object. Thus, the result must be passed to the `list` function. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if using map and lambda **is** a constraint in your exercise, but you
don't need them, by the way

```
>>> [[i*j for j in range(i)] for i in range(1,6)]
[[0], [0, 2], [0, 3, 6], [0, 4, 8, 12], [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am trying to use map and lambdas for this exercise, but it is very helpful to know an alternative way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want in pure functional programming as you said then you can try this :

```
print(list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda z:z*x,list(range(x)))),range(1,6))))
```

output:

```
[[0], [0, 2], [0, 3, 6], [0, 4, 8, 12], [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]]
```